# Pronunciation of the /s/ letter in English language

Tags: pronunciation

I have a question about pronunciation 
Of /s/ sound after ‘th’ sound like these situations

With /S/eventy-five
Or
With /S/ilver

to make things simple since I’m not a native speaker 
Provide a word or something as simple as a word if it’s possible

Thanks for your help..!

Comment: It's pronounced the same way after the 'th' as it is after most sounds. We might change the pronunciation of the 'th', but not the /s/.

Comment: @PeterShor: I wonder what the source of confusion might be here, i.e. something a non-native ear might be detecting that isn't quite obvious, much less striking, to a native speaker? "Two yoots," sure, but that's the "th" sound changing, as you just pointed out. The "s" sound? Hmm ...

Comment: I'm not sufficiently confident to make this an answer, but for me an /s/ following the 'th' sound is more sibilant than usual owing to the proximity of my tongue to my teeth after making the "th". There is more hissing or whistling than usual at the start of the /s/ if I'm slow moving my tongue back. If you put your tongue just behind your teeth and try to make an /s/, and compare that to making an /s/ with your tongue being near your alveolar ridge (mid-top ridge of mouth), that's an exaggerated version of the difference I'm noticing.

Comment: There is a good example — the word ‘withstand’ — and it's pronounced here: https://forvo.com/word/withstand/#en. We see that the first man (from the US) confirms TaliesinMerlin's opinion making this sibilant at the start /s/ sound.

Comment: However, the tongue can move fast and then all sounds are ordinary to my ear as here: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/withstand.